# Developer Mode on VSN Mobil V.50

Tags: usb-debugging

I have a phone made by VSN Mobil called the V.50.  It's running their own mod of 4.4.2.  The normal method of tapping Build Number seven times to access Developer Mode does not work.  I just need to be able to install and debug.

Has anyone successfully gotten a V.50 into Developer Mode?

[UPDATE]

After some back and forth with VSN's customer support, VSN confirmed that there is "no access" to Developer Mode on the V.50.  The V.45 does display the Build Number and it can be tapped seven times to access Developer Mode, but the V.50 does not display Build Number, so therefore Developer Mode is inaccessible.  Boo VSN.

Comment: It might be possible that the developer mode is only hidden, but still accessible using 3rd-party apps. You might try [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.selfip.unet.developer_options) and other similar apps from Play Store.

Comment: @AndrewT, I installed Developer Options by uDroid and it worked.  If you make it into an answer, I'll select it and upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes this can happen, whether it's a decision made by the vendor, or it's really [an accidental mistake](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/92499/enable-developer-options-on-samsung-galaxy-tab-s-8-4).

However, it doesn't mean that the whole developer option is removed from the system (though, *this could really happen*, as shown on the linked question). The workaround is to invoke the developer option through 3rd-party apps, such as:

- [Developer Options](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.selfip.unet.developer_options) by uDroid (free)
- [Developer Options](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.singlebyte.devshortcut) by SingleByte (free)
- [Developer Settings Shortcut](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fungaljungal.devsettingswidget) (free)
- and many more...

If it's still inaccessible, then the developer option might be really removed from the ROM, and you should contact the vendor regarding this.