# Enable Developer Options on Samsung Galaxy Tab S 8.4

Tags: settings, samsung

I'm having trouble enabling developer options on my Samsung Galaxy Tab S 8.4 tablet. I click the build number 7 times and get the toast telling me it's enabled, but it doesn't appear in the menu items.

[image: dev opt not shown on the menu]

As you can see, developer options are unlocked but it's not listed in the menu items.

**UPDATE:**

So it turns out this is a problem with the latest version of Android on this device, Samsung  were not aware of this bug but are now and it will be fixed in the next release!

Comment: Well, try hiding then To hide them, go to Settings>apps>swipe over to all apps>scroll down to settings storage>tap clear data.Once you hide, then again try tapping 7 times over the build number to activate them and see if that shows you the ???

Comment: Based from [Samsung's FAQ](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/faq/FAQ00071907/97970), you already did the correct procedure and it should appear under Settings > General > Developer options. Might be a silly question, but have you tried closing and opening the Settings again (maybe it needs to be refreshed)?

Comment: Yes, I have restarted the tablet, ive restored it a few times and still it does not appear.

Comment: Peter, I'm following your instructions but the clear data button is blank.

Comment: Well, if clear data button is blank means no data is available to clear up ! Now that's weird ...

Comment: Was the response by Samsung itself? It would be better if you could post it as an answer, and quoting Samsung's response, because it's the official and best answer. In fact, it's [encouraged to answer your own question](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a desperate idea, but try rotating your device between portrait and landscape. It doesn't seem likely, but it's possible somebody at Samsung may have accidentally left out the Developer Options item from the layout or changed something that caused it to remain invisible.

If that doesn't work, try installing an app from the Play Store that acts as a shortcut to developer settings ([like this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fungaljungal.devsettingswidget)). It's not the most elegant solution, but it should be enough to get you there.

Comment: Thanks Cody, I tried the shortcut apps before and they didn't work, but was worth a shot!

Comment: That sounds like a bigger problem. If firing off an intent to the system to load Developer Options isn't working, it's not just an issue of the Settings app failing to show it in the list. You might want to go straight to Samsung's Support channels and report the issue officially.

Answer (score 0):

According to OP who supposedly asked Samsung's Support channels directly,

> So it turns out this is a problem with the latest version of Android on this device, Samsung were not aware of this bug but are now and it will be fixed in the next release!